# (vim) regex: masking text with help of pattern

Tags: regex, vim, replace

Am i correct to understand, that the definition

```
:range s[ubstitute]/pattern/string/cgiI
```

suggests that in the string part indeed only strings are to be used, that is patterns not allowed? What i would like to do is do replacement of say any N symbols at position M with X*N symbols, so i would have liked to use something like this:

```
:%s/^\(.\{10}\).\{28}/\1X\{28}/g
```

Which does not work because `\{28}` is interpreted literally.

Is writing the 28 XXXXX...X in the replace part the only possibility?

Comment: In Perl you could use `s/regex/'X' x 28/ge`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use expressions in the replacement part via `\=`. You have to access the match via `submatch()`, and join it together with the static string, which you can generate via `repeat()`:

```
:%s/^\(.\{10}\).\{28}/\=submatch(1) . repeat('X',28)/g
```

Answer (score 2):

The only regex constructs allowed in the replacement part are numbered groups: `\1 \2 \3`  etc.  The repeating construct `{28}` is not valid there, though it's a clever idea.  You'll have to use 28 X's.

Comment: Of course, you can always abuse Vim's buffers to avoid typing out the 28 X's manually (i.e. type out the command in insert mode, complete with `28aX`, stick it in a buffer, then load the buffer's contents in Ex mode).

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is using a expression in the replacement part:

```
:%s/^\(.\{10}\).\{28}/\=submatch(1).repeat("X",28)/g
```

The first matched group is obtained with `submatch(1)`. For more information see `:h sub-replace-expression`.